# Can I jump to a jump by its number in vim?

Tags: vim

If I execute `:jumps` command it shows me a list of previously visited files/lines

```
jump line  col file/text
  97  152    0   ...
```

Can I jump to a jump by the jump number without iterating over them by pressing CTRL+o and CTRL+i?

I've not yet tried this link where they suggest to create a function: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations

But cannot it really be achieved without it? Isn't there some built-in command in vim to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the function `GotoJump()` described in the link: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations

I figured out that you have to type the jump number in normal mode and then press CTRL+o